# Rails 4 mongoid display error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, save, mongoid

I am using mongoid with rails. I want to save, and if it is does not save and fail I would like to be able to see the error message.
I would like to see Mongoid error message, why it does not save

```
if @book.save
  redirect_to book_path(@book)
else
  flash.now[:error] = "The book can not be saved, please enter information."
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mongoid uses](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html) the [ActiveRecord interface](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-errors), so you can examine the errors like this:

```
@book.errors
```